# How to export/Import a project correctly?

Tags: android, eclipse

As a newbie, I am trying to develop one basic App. Always, I export it, and import it in other PC and I get errors everywhere. I have tried with some others and I get the same problems.
This errors appeared:

```
"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: 'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/workspace/Share it Fast/libs/android-support-v4.jar' in project 'Share it Fast' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    Share it Fast       Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    Share it Fast       Unknown Java Problem
Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.  Share it Fast       Unknown Android Target Problem
Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.  Share it Fast       Unknown Android Target Problem "
```

I think they are generated because I didn't put the library files. But, there are other errors.
The question is: How to IMPORT and EXPORT correctly? I don't want to get more errors or start again.
Thanks.

Comment: Rename your directory "Share it Fast" to "Share_it_Fast" and try again.

Comment: @Agilox I renamed my "directory" to Share_it_fast i think that you mean the name of the app where i have src, res, libs etc. 
And i am getting the next errors:
[2014-03-07 17:10:07 - Share it fast] Parser exception for /Share it fast/AndroidManifest.xml: Final de archivo prematuro.
[2014-03-07 17:10:22 - Share_it_fast] Parser exception for /Share_it_fast/AndroidManifest.xml: Final de archivo prematuro.

Final de archivo prematuro=(in English) End of premature file.

Comment: After renaming, you have to import again. Delete the existing one from directory before importing.

Comment: @Agilox and, when i try to open any src, i get this error: http://i59.tinypic.com/30jmi4w.jpg

Comment: Select the project and click on Project menu >> Clear. If you get more error, paste them here.

Comment: @Agilox LOL, i cant import it again, i renamed, deleted (but not from disk obviously) and when i import it again, nothing happend :|

Comment: @Agilox Thanks, now i can open files normally. But i Can`t remember where i put the Target sdk and i get this error: [2014-03-07 17:48:05 - Share it Fast] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'

Comment: @FabianMontossi Check your AndroidManifest.XML file